# FlowJS: How to use union types and boolean literals

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Flow questions seem to garner few answers, but here goes:

```js
type Base = {
  foo: string,
  bar: string
}
type Derived1 = Base & {
  conditional: false
}
type Derived2 = Base & {
  conditional: true,
  baz: string
}

type One = {
  foo: string,
  bar: string,
  conditional: boolean
}
type Two = One & {
  baz: string
}

type Return1 = Derived1 | Derived2  // fails

type Return2 = One | Two  // works, but not desired

function test(conditional: boolean): Return1 {
  return {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar",
    conditional,
    ...conditional ? {baz: "baz"} : {}
  }
}
```

It is preferable for the return value of `test` to be one of the `Derived*` types (`Return1` rather than `Return2`), where the `conditional` property is a boolean literal.

The intention is for flow to understand that if `conditional` is `true`, then the object `test` returns **must** contain `baz` and vice versa.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow isn't quite smart enough to figure it out for you.  You have to do something like:

```
function test(conditional: boolean): Return1 {

  const base = {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar",
  }

  if (!conditional) {
    return Object.assign({}, base, { conditional });
  } else {
    const result: Derived2 = Object.assign({}, base, { conditional }, {baz: "baz"});
    return result;
  }
}
```

More info here: https://flow.org/blog/2016/07/01/New-Unions-Intersections/